# System.OutOfMemoryException error while using nested cursors in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor, nested-loops

i tried to execute the sql code given in this documentation :
 [Mirosoft documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325187/fr)

everything is OK, but it take 1 minute to execute the query ( 4320 rows in results )
and it shows this error message :

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

can you help me in using nested cursors in sql server without causing Memory exceptions ! 
Thank you !

Comment: its probably an OutOfMemoryException from the Management Studio, try a workaround descript on this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2874903

Comment: Thanks for your answer  deterministicFail ! I tried this solution in Mirosoft Support, but i still get the same problem, anyway after updating my query, it didn't show me that problem, i guess the problem was in my query syntaxe !